# why passing names(.) to forumla in rename_with doesn't work?

Tags: r, dplyr

Not sure why the first one has an error but the second line works? My understanding was using  names(.) in the formulas tells R to use the data before pipe operator. It seems to work for .cols argument but not for formula.

```
iris%>%rename_with(~gsub("Petal","_",names(.)),all_of(names(.)))
iris%>%rename_with(~~gsub("Petal","_",names(iris)),all_of(names(.)))
```

Comment: `iris%>%rename_with(~gsub("Petal","_",.x)))` ?  I think .x inside the gsub function rather than names(.) because you want to apply the function to each element in the list of names, you don't want to pass the entire list of names as an argument each time it is applied. See the examples at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rename.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation on what went wrong  @PaulStaffordAllen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rename_with` applies a function to the *names* of the passed data frame. The function should be one that, given the vector of names, returns the altered names, so the syntax is much simpler than you are trying to make it:

```r
iris %>%
  rename_with(~ gsub("Petal", "_", .x))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width _.Length _.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5      1.4     0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0      1.4     0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2      1.3     0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1      1.5     0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6      1.4     0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9      1.7     0.4  setosa
#... etc
```

Comment: Thanks, so in this case replacing .x with . will also give the same outcome since rename_with automatically takes names of the passed data frame. I tried it out and it worked. Is there any general difference between using . and .x when using pipes? @Allan Cameron